# Splitting feature into fixed measurements

Tags: qgis, features, splitting, parcel

For my thesis I'm trying to split featuring in QGis into multiple new features of a fixed size (5.5 by 2 meters). I think it would be the equivalent of ArcGIS' Parcel Division tool, but unfortunately I don't have the ArcEditor/ArcInfo license. I already downloaded some plugins but I can't manage to find the solution. Hope you can help!

I've uploaded some pictures I edited with paint to visualize what I mean. NB: they're not only straight squares, but also parallellograms.

[image]

[image]

[[image][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaYDe.png)

[image]

Comment: Do you have parallel lines already? Are they parallel to any particular edge of the polygon?